# Python dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists, one of them is a list of values and the other is a list of dates.

I want to create a dictionary with values and dates as keys. But a lot of the values have the same "key" (date). I need to add the values with the same date (same key) together before making a dictionary.

Both of the lists have the same number of elements but the list of dates has some values duplicated (since every date has more than one value).

What would be the best way to group the values (add them together) based on the keys (dates)?

Examples of the lists

```
dates = [datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0)]

values = [2,7,4,8,4]

I want my dictionary to look like this:
dict = [datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0):13,datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0):8,datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0):4]
```

Comment: What do you mean add the values? add them to a list, or simple arithematic addition?

Comment: Use code to help you describe the problem, e.g, `a = [1,2,3]`, `b = ['foo', 'bar']`, etc.

Comment: can you show how your dictionary look likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have repeating dates and want to group the values for repeating keys, use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for dte, val in zip(dates, values):
    d[dte] += val
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0): 13, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0): 12})
```

Or using a normal dict and `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
for dte, val in zip(dates,values):
    d.setdefault(dte,0)
    d[dte] += val
```

Lastly you can use dict.get with a default value of 0:

```
d = {}
for dte, val in zip(dates,values):
    d[dte] = d.get(dte, 0) + val
```

The `defaultdict` is going to be the fastest approach as it is designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Just a small note: `defaultdict` is a dictionary-like object, which sets default value for, if there is no value by the accessed key.

Comment: Nice, this works, I only have to add the values together for every key and I'm done :)
Thank you

Comment: @LukaPerović, I edited for your edit, you can += the values of you actually want to add as in addition, I think you output should only have two keys though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming if this is your input,

```
>>> dates = ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03']
>>> values = [10, 15, 10, 10]
```

Combine the values,

```
>>> data = zip(dates, values)
[('2015-01-01', 10), ('2015-01-01', 15), ('2015-01-02', 10), ('2015-01-03', 10)]
```

Aggregate the values for same dates,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> new_data = []
>>> for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x[0]):
        tmp = [key, 0]    #: '0' is the default value
        for thing in group:
            tmp[1] += thing[1]
    new_data.append(tmp)
```

Print the `new_data`,

```
>>> new_data
[['2015-01-01', 25], ['2015-01-02', 10], ['2015-01-03', 10]]
```

Now build the final dictionary,

```
>>> dict(new_data)
{'2015-01-03': 10, '2015-01-02': 10, '2015-01-01': 25}
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` and `defaultdict` are pretty unnecessary for this. I think that this is simpler and easier to read.

```
dates = [datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0)]
values = [2,7,4,8,4]

combined = {}
for (date,value) in zip(dates,values):
  if date in combined:
    combined[date] += value
  else:
    combined[date] = value
```

---

**Performance analysis**

I'm not saying that `defaultdict` is a bad solution, I was only pointing out that it requires more tacit knowledge to use without pitfalls.

It is not however the fastest solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
import timeit

dates = [datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0),datetime(2014, 3, 1, 0, 0)]
values = [2,7,4,8,4]

def combine_default_dict(dates=dates,values=values):
  d = defaultdict(int)
  for dte, val in zip(dates, values):
      d[dte] += val
  return d

def combine_setdefault(dates=dates,values=values):
  d = {}
  for dte, val in zip(dates,values):
      d.setdefault(dte,0)
      d[dte] += val
  return d

def combine_get(dates=dates,values=values):
  d = {}
  for dte, val in zip(dates,values):
      d[dte] = d.get(dte, 0) + val
  return d

def combine_contains(dates=dates,values=values):
  d = {}
  for (date,value) in zip(dates,values):
    if date in d:
      d[date] += value
    else:
      d[date] = value
  return d

def time_them(number=100000):
  for func_name in [k for k in sorted(globals().keys()) if k.startswith('combine_')]:
    timer = timeit.Timer("{0}()".format(func_name),"from __main__ import {0}".format(func_name))
    time_taken = timer.timeit(number=number)
    print "{0} - {1}".format(time_taken,func_name)
```

Yields:

```
>>> time_them()
0.388070106506 - combine_contains
0.485766887665 - combine_default_dict
0.415601968765 - combine_get
0.472551822662 - combine_setdefault
```

I've tried it on a couple of different machines and python versions. `combine_default_dict` competes with `combine_setdefault` for the slowest. `combine_contains` has been consistently the fastest.

Comment: Using a defaultdict  for exactly what is was designed for is hard to read?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I'm not saying it's hard to read, just comparatively harder. `defaultdict`'s behaviour requires implicit understanding of its implementation. You have to understand, implicitly that if you ever ask it for a key's value, you're going to get back the default value and instantiate that key with the default value at the same time.